# Приравнивание в блоке switch

Tags: c#

Мне нужно оценить значение одной переменной и на ее основе выставить значение другой переменной. Скажите, как мне это  правильно сделать в блоке `switch / case`?

```
 string nCodeTypeKa = "";
 switch (apparat)
    {
    case "Ресурс":
        nCodeTypeKa = "sdf"; // Вот так же нельзя? А как правильно?
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему вы решили, что так нельзя? [Очень даже можно](http://ideone.com/I1u5id). Только `break` в конце каждого `case`'а не забывайте.

Answer (score 1):

Так можно делать. Только не забывайте про break и открытие\закрытие операторных скобок.

```
     string nCodeTypeKa = "";
     switch (apparat)
        {
          case "Ресурс":
          {
            nCodeTypeKa = "sdf";
            break;
          }
        }
```